# SwiftKeychainWrapper xctest returning nil

Tags: keychain, xctest

I'm trying to do a basic unit test with the keychain. I can set the value for a key successfully ('setString' returns true), however, when I try to retrieve the value, even after a 5 second delay, the return is still nil:

```
class MyKeychainTest: XCTestCase {
    func checkKeychain(timer: NSTimer) {
        debugPrint("check keychain...")
        let userInfo = timer.userInfo as! [String: AnyObject]
        let expectation = userInfo["expectation"] as! XCTestExpectation

        let res = KeychainWrapper.objectForKey("myKey")
        debugPrint("got res: \(res)")
        XCTAssertNotNil(res)

        expectation.fulfill()
    }

    func testKeychain() {
        let expectation = expectationWithDescription("gotKey")
        let success = KeychainWrapper.setString("foo", forKey: "myKey")
        debugPrint("set key?: \(success)")

        NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(5.0, target: self, selector: #selector(self.checkKeychain)
        , userInfo: ["expectation": expectation ], repeats: false)

        self.waitForExpectationsWithTimeout(10, handler: nil)
    }
}
```

Any ideas on what can cause this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Accidentally used the wrong method to get the key. Instead of `KeychainWrapper.objectForKey("myKey")` using `KeychainWrapper.stringForKey("myKey")` works. Strange that an object isn't even returned though in the former case